# Can't figure out a Python exercise with dictionaries

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
shoppingList = ["banana","orange","apple"]

inventory = {"banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
    }

prices = {"banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
    }

def calculateBill(food):
    total = 0
    for k in food:
        total += prices[k]
    return total
calculateBill(shoppingList)
```

The exercise tells me to complete the function following these instructions:

1. Don't add the price of an article in your bill if it is not in your inventory.
2. After you buy an article, substract one from the inventory.

I don't know how to do it and I don't know if I have any other mistakes in my code.

If it isn't clear, the value in inventory is the stock of that item, and the value in "prices" is the price.

Comment: So what have you tried doing to understand the code, really?

Comment: should comida = food?

Comment: I haven't tried anything becaus I have no idea

Comment: It was origininally in Spanish, sorry

Comment: @FedeCouti if you can't even begin an exercise then it's a poor question for stack overflow. There's no actual question here, just an exercise for YOU, the student :). Go try some stuff, get dirty, and ask us why your code is breaking.

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: This isn't a homework site. It sounds like you need to read the documentation for (the type of data structure represented by `inventory`), to discover: how to check whether a key is present; how to get the value at a key; how to modify the value at a key. This is an exercise about working with and modifying a particular data structure.

Comment: Or in other words: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't see `comida` defined anywhere before its use. I'll assume that by `comida`, you mean `food`.

Here is a simple solution:

```
def calculateBill(food):
    total = 0
    for k in food:
        if inventory.get(k, 0) > 0:
            total += prices[k]                # updates total
            inventory[k] = inventory[k] - 1   # updates inventory
    return total
```

Comment: `if inventory[k] > 0` gives a `KeyError` under a possible precondition

Comment: There's a better way. `if inventory.get(k,0) > 0`.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Thanks, I didn't know about that. (I'm a python newbie myself.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
def calculateBill(food):
    total = 0
    for k in food:
        if k in inventory:
            if inventory[k] > 0:
                total += prices[k]
                inventory[k] = inventory[k] - 1
            else:
                print 'There are no %s in stock' % k
        else:
            print 'dont stock %s' % k
    return total
```

For 1)

```
if k in inventory:
```

Will check if the key is present in your inventory dict.

For 2)

```
inventory[k] = inventory[k] - 1
```

Will substract 1 from your inventory

One flaw in this code is that it does not check that the inventory count is above 0 before allowing to buy. So

```
if inventory[k] > 0:
```

Does this.

Comment: no need to call `dict.keys` on inventory, just do `if k in inventory` however there's an easier way to do this using `dict.get`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete solution.

```
class Error(Exception):
    """Base class for Exceptions in this module"""
    pass

class QtyError(Error):
    """Errors related to the quantity of food products ordered"""
    pass

def calculateBill(food):

    def buy_item(food_item, qty=1, inv_dict=None, prices_dict=None):
        get_price = lambda item,price_dct: price_dct.get(item,9999999)
        if inv_dict is None:
            inv_dict = inventory
        if prices_dict is None:
            prices_dict = prices
        if inv_dict.get(food_item, 0) >= qty:
            inv_dict[food_item] -= qty
            return sum(get_price(food_item, prices_dict) for _ in range(qty))
        else:
            raise QtyError("Cannot purchase item '{0}' of quantity {1}, inventory only contains {2} of '{0}'".format(food_item, qty, inv_dict.get(food_item,0)))

    total = sum(buy_item(food_item, 1, inventory, prices) for food_item in food)
    return total
```